# Loop through list and insert into array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list like this:

```
<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId='' data-parentOrder='1'>
    <a href='/category/edit/1'>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='10' data-parentCategoryId='1' data-parentOrder='2'>
    <a href='/category/edit/10'>General/Legal</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='15' data-parentCategoryId='2' data-parentOrder='3'>
    <a href='/category/edit/15'>Home, Help &amp; Links</a>
</li>
```

I want to loop over every element with the class 'category', get the data attributes, and insert those into an array.

```
var categoryData = Object.create(null);
var myArray = [];

$('.category').each(function() {
    categoryData.categoryId = category.attr('data-categoryId');
    categoryData.parentCategoryId = category.attr('data-parentCategoryId');
    categoryData.childOrder = category.attr('data-child-order');
    categoryData.parentOrder = category.attr('data-parent-order');

    myArray.push(categoryData);
});
```

But currently it only grabs the data from the first element and then inserts that into the array multiple times.

```
[ 
    0 => [ categoryId => 1, parentCategoryId => , childOrder => , parentOrder => 1 ], 
    1 => [ categoryId => 1, parentCategoryId => , childOrder => , parentOrder => 1 ], 
    2 => [ categoryId => 1, parentCategoryId => , childOrder => , parentOrder => 1 ]
]
```

What I want is:

```
[ 
    0 => [ categoryId => 1, parentCategoryId => , childOrder => , parentOrder => 1 ], 
    1 => [ categoryId => 10, parentCategoryId => 1, childOrder => , parentOrder => 2 ], 
    2 => [ categoryId => 15, parentCategoryId => 2, childOrder => , parentOrder => 3 ]
]
```

Comment: You need to Object.create on every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also needed to change ref to category

```js
var myArray = [];

$('.category').each(function() {
    let categoryData = Object.create(null);
    categoryData.categoryId = $(this).attr('data-categoryId');
    categoryData.parentCategoryId = $(this).attr('data-parentCategoryId');
    categoryData.childOrder = $(this).attr('data-child-order');
    categoryData.parentOrder = $(this).attr('data-parent-order');

    myArray.push(categoryData);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId='' data-parentOrder='1'>
    <a href='/category/edit/1'>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='10' data-parentCategoryId='1' data-parentOrder='2'>
    <a href='/category/edit/10'>General/Legal</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='15' data-parentCategoryId='2' data-parentOrder='3'>
    <a href='/category/edit/15'>Home, Help &amp; Links</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, $(this) is what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [];

$('.category').each(function() {
  var categoryId = $(this).attr('data-categoryId');
  var parentCategoryId = $(this).attr('data-parentCategoryId');
  var childOrder = $(this).attr('data-child-order');
  var parentOrder = $(this).attr('data-parent-order');

  myArray.push({categoryId , parentCategoryId ,childOrder,parentOrder  });
})
```

This might work

Answer (score 1):

Objects are [reference types](https://gist.github.com/branneman/7fb06d8a74d7e6d4cbcf75c50fec599c).

In your loop, you're only setting properties of the same object `categoryData` instead of creating a new one.

So in the end, your array contains multiple references to the same object at every index. This is why you see the same values (of the last category element) on every element of your result array.

The solution is to create **an object for each** category element in the loop

```
$('.category').each(function() {
 const data = {
    categoryId: category.attr('data-categoryId'),
    parentCategoryId: category.attr('data-parentCategoryId'),
    childOrder: category.attr('data-child-order');
    parentOrder: category.attr('data-parent-order')
  };

  myArray.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to push a new object each time :)

```
$('.category').each(function() {
    myArray.push({
        categoryId: category.attr('data-categoryId'),
        parentCategoryId: category.attr('data-parentCategoryId'),
        childOrder: category.attr('data-child-order'),
        parentOrder: category.attr('data-parent-order'),
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will get you sorted:

```js
var myArray = [];

$('.category').each(function() {
    let categoryData = Object.create(null);
    categoryData.categoryId = $(this).attr('data-categoryId');
    categoryData.parentCategoryId = $(this).attr('data-parentCategoryId');
    categoryData.childOrder = $(this).attr('data-child-order');
    categoryData.parentOrder = $(this).attr('data-parentOrder');
    myArray.push(categoryData);
});
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='1' data-parentCategoryId='' data-parentOrder='1'>
    <a href='/category/edit/1'>Business Basics</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='10' data-parentCategoryId='1' data-parentOrder='2'>
    <a href='/category/edit/10'>General/Legal</a>
</li>

<li class='category parent-category' data-categoryId='15' data-parentCategoryId='2' data-parentOrder='3'>
    <a href='/category/edit/15'>Home, Help &amp; Links</a>
</li>
```

Just make sure to insert your "childOrder" in your html, otherwise the result will keep showing "undefined".